# Returning 2 columns from MySql using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using php and jquery to populate a dependent dropdown with information from a mysql database. I have the dependent dropdowns working okay, but I also need to return another column from the db and include it in the JSON array such that it is available to be manipulated in javascript with an onclick event.

```
$area = $_GET["area"];

    $query = "SELECT proxies.name FROM proxies INNER JOIN areas ON proxies.area_id=areas.id WHERE areas.name LIKE '{$area}'";
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $proxies = [];

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        array_push($proxies, $row["name"],["price"]);
    }

    echo json_encode($proxies);
```

using AND (proxies.price) in the mysql statement just throws an error that says the index is undefined. How do I return the additional column so that I can take what the user selects, and hold other info from the record and use it is as a variable?

Comment: it's not AND proxies.price, it's `SELECT proxies.name, proxies.price FROM...`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did try that too.

Comment: Also change `array_push($proxies, $row["name"],["price"]);` to `array_push($proxies, $row["name"],$row["price"]);`

Comment: Thank you, that does return the other column, but it includes it as an additional item(s) in the array, I need it to be tied to the $row["name”] variable for each record.